# Multiple writes on same socket c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mutex

I'm currently trying to develop a server and some clients which communicate with each other using something like a proxy in the middle. The "proxy" will have sockets opened to every client and server on the system. This means that I'm currently using threads to keep all the connections opened. Every time a client decides to send a message it uses its socket with the proxy and sends the message. Then the proxy will propagate the message to every other node using the respective socket.

As you can see, a node can be receiving messages by having the proxy writing on the socket or a node may want to send messages by writing on the socket. 
How do I guarantee that the content in the socket does not get overwritten ? Do I have to use mutexes to lock the access to the socket ? What is a good practice to solve this problem ?

Comment: **Be careful**  If a client sends a single message with a single call to `write`, the proxy may end up reading that message with two calls to `read`.  Similarly if a client sends two messages with two calls to `write`, the proxy may read them both with a single call to read.  You will need some buffering in the proxy in order to avoid fragmenting messages, and (in particular) to avoid other clients receiving  two messages interleaved.

Comment: Or the client sends two messages, and the proxy ends up `read`ing all of one message and a bit of the second (and then a second call ends up with the rest).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Without knowing what socket we're talking about, you can't state that. UDP does not fragment. That's inherent to UDP; because it's connectionless you can't concatenate the results from two `read`s. So `read` is not allowed to fragment UDP packets.

Comment: You don't have to use threads at all, and it will be much much easier without threads.

Comment: @MSalters - Oooh, good catch!  You are quite right, I was assuming TCP sockets.  (But if you use UDP, then you sacrifice reliability - which may not matter, particularly if this if for a LAN-only application).

Answer (score 1):

Connections are bi-directional. Content going one way does not overwrite content going the other way. No mutex is needed for this.

Besides, you couldn't use a mutex anyway, as both sides of the connection are separate.